# Where is the camera tab/properties in blender 2.9?

Tags: animation, camera

I downloaded blender 2.9, however when I'm trying to put a background image with the camera as in the 2.8 version, I can't find it. I'm attaching an image. Maybe it can help, maybe not. But I can't seem to find anything online that can help me with this annoying problem.[image]

Comment: Is the camera selected?

Comment: ... lol thanks. i hadn't selected it. don't know what i thought.